# How to implement SSO using Azure AD to only one of the website that has a different sub-domain but same domain as other websites?

Tags: azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, subdomain

url : (www.test-organisation.com) where "organisation.com" is the domain and "test" is the sub-domain
We have multiple websites, eg, (www.test-organisation.com), (www.dev-organisation.com), (www.prod-organisation.com)
Will implementing SSO on (www.test-organisation.com), lead to SSO getting implemented on (www.dev-organisation.com) & (www.prod-organisation.com) as well, because they have same domain names?? Or Azure AD considers the url over domain??

Comment: Your apps choose whether or not to send the user to authenticate. How are you configuring authentication?

Comment: Hey Juunas, We are using Azure AD to authenticate user using the SAML request. I am not sure whether the the Provider Metadata endpoints that we will get from Azure  will be specific to the URL or just to the domain. If it just takes domain into consideration, then when i will enable SSO, it will be enabled for both dev and prod environment. If it takes URL into consideration i will be able to enable the SSO for just the dev environment first.

Comment: @juunas Could you please help me with this.

Comment: Hmm, I haven't worked with SAML a lot.. So honestly I'm not sure :\